# How to find the connection between variables

Tags: independence, joint-distribution

Assume that you want to approximate your joint distribution on set of variables via decomposing it into several smaller distributions. Assume that you don't know any prior knowledge about the statistical or algebraic connection between variables; the only input is a set of samples from variables. How do you claim whether some variables tend to be dependent/independent? (note that this is more than just calculating correlation, which is indeed a linear operation.)

Comment: I guess there is no straight answer to this question. You could use scatterplot to start to get an idea of the relationships

Comment: (+1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation might offer some useful ideas.  Also check out the material on our site about [copulas](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=copula).

Comment: You can use 'dependence measures' and 'conditional dependence measures', but usually the computational complexity is combinatorially high, and hence impractical to recover the full conditional independence structure if you have many variables.